# Firefox webdriver-Changing the default download location at runtime

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How do I set a default download location for Firefox at runtime. Is there any way to prevent the folder selection popup from coming?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the code found on this [blog](http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/)

Something like:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir",getcwd())
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Hope that helps.